# Missing fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.* when upgrading angular-bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, glyphicons, angular-bootstrap

I am using Yeoman and the cg-angular generator to scaffold an angular app. This was initially working fine, but I recently upgraded `angular-bootstrap` from `0.10` to `0.11` to get hold of a new feature regarding modal sizes. After doing this I noticed that I get the following errors in the developer console on Chrome.

```
GET http://localhost:9001/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff  angular-ui-router.js:3702 
GET http://localhost:9001/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf   :9001/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf:1
```

I am using version `3.1.1` of `bootstrap`.

If I upgrade `bootstrap` to the latest which is `3.3.4`. Then I get some different errors:

```
GET http://fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED angular-animate.js:442
GET http://fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff  net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff:1
GET http://fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf   net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf:1
```

I should say that I am seeing these errors when running locally with `grunt serve`

Also, if I upgrade `boostrap`, but keep `angular-bootstrap` at `0.10` then I don't have these problems.

I also, have the following my `Gruntfile.js`:

```
copy: {
        main: {
            files: [
                {src: ['bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/**'], dest: 'dist/', filter: 'isFile', expand: true},
                {src: ['bower_components/bootstrap/fonts/**'], dest: 'dist/', filter: 'isFile', expand: true}
            ]
        }
    }
```

Although, like I said I am seeing these missing glyphicons when running locally, so this grunt task shouldn't be coming in to play.

I've grepped through the `angular-bootstrap` code and what is confusing is that there doesn't seem to be any direct references to the glyphicon fonts in their code, so it's a bit odd how upgrading this module could cause these errors.

Has anyone else had any issues with glyphicons when upgrading `angular-bootstrap`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The less compilation happens in the browser when you're running the site with `grunt serve` so the default path for the fonts (`../fonts/`) is not relative to the bootstrap less files. To fix it just override the font path (in `app.less` by default)

```
@icon-font-path: "bower_components/bootstrap/fonts/";
```

Maybe something in angular-bootstrap started using glyphicons in 0.11 that's why you see this after upgrade.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I had `@fa-font-path: "bower_components/font-awesome/fonts";` in my `app.less` file that was put there by the generator. It seems that the previous version of `angular-bootstrap` must have been using the glyphicons from FontAwesome instead. Cheers.